# How can store size of vector first then do Condition

Tags: c++, vector

I cast int value in vector then for `vector.size()` condition ,do something
my condition is `if(values.size()==1)` in first time always vector.size() is 1,how can wait to get all int value and doesn't //dosomething of this condition quickly after get first int,need an other condition??

```
vector<int> values;
while(true){
   int key = mySwitch.getReceivedValue();
                values.push_back(key);
                if (values.size() == 1  ) { //not do this in first time quickly wait,maybe vector size is bigger

                    //do something
                                }

                } else if (values.size() > 1 && values.size() <= 7) {
                    //do something

                } else if (values.size() > 7) {
                    values.clear();
                    continue;
                }
}
```

Comment: Take the first condition out of the `if-else` chain and put it at the end? I'm not sure I understand the objective.

Comment: @JamesRoot your mean is I took first condition at the end of loop??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have a loop, and the first time in the loop you don't want to do anything when the size of the vector is one?

Then just add a boolean flag, which you set to e.g. true before the loop, then last in the loop you set it to false, and in the check for the size you also check this flag.

Something like

```
bool first_time_in_loop = true;
for (...)
{
    ...
    if (!first_time_in_loop && values.size() == 1)
    {
        // Will not be performed the first time the loop iterates
        ...
    }
    else if ...
    ...
    first_time_in_loop = false;
}
```

Comment: tnx but my mean first get int value 1 or 2 then check condition and do something,my code quickly ,when get first int value execute first condition and program doesn't wait maybe vector is bigger.your code as same